# Where is the jar for software.amazon.kinesis.*

Tags: amazon-kinesis

0 for Java users:

I've been following this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kcl-migration.html
and it wants me to import these:

```
    import software.amazon.kinesis.exceptions.InvalidStateException;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.exceptions.ShutdownException;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.InitializationInput;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.LeaseLostInput;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ProcessRecordsInput;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ShardEndedInput;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ShutdownRequestedInput;
    import software.amazon.kinesis.processor.ShardRecordProcessor;
```

I am migrating the sample files downloaded from AWS SDK 2.0 from Java, which looks like Amazon hasn't gotten around to migrate?   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/advanced-topics.html

But for the life of me, I cannot locate the JAR file that contains the software.amazon.kinesis.* classes, even after googling and searching Maven Central, etc., for a few hours.

Here is my migrated target/pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>samples</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
          <version>1.11.486</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.3</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Where's the Jar?  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the jar: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.kinesis/amazon-kinesis-client

And you need to add the following dependency to your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jar worked, and here is the result of my migration for those doing the same:

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesis;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ResourceNotFoundException;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatch.CloudWatchAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.kinesis.common.ConfigsBuilder;
import software.amazon.kinesis.common.InitialPositionInStream;
import software.amazon.kinesis.coordinator.Scheduler;

/**
 * Sample Amazon Kinesis Application.
 */
public final class AmazonKinesisApplicationSample {

    /*
     * Before running the code:
     *      Fill in your AWS access credentials in the provided credentials
     *      file template, and be sure to move the file to the default location
     *      (/home/user1/.aws/credentials) where the sample code will load the
     *      credentials from.
     *      https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential
     *
     * WARNING:
     *      To avoid accidental leakage of your credentials, DO NOT keep
     *      the credentials file in your source directory.
     */

    public static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME = "myFirstStream";

    private static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME = "SampleKinesisApplication";

    // Initial position in the stream when the application starts up for the first time.
    // Position can be one of LATEST (most recent data) or TRIM_HORIZON (oldest available data)
    private static final InitialPositionInStream SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM =
            InitialPositionInStream.LATEST;

    private static ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    private static void init() {
        // Ensure the JVM will refresh the cached IP values of AWS resources (e.g. service endpoints).
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");

        /*
         * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [user1]
         * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
         * (/home/user1/.aws/credentials).
         */
        credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("user1");
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                    + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                    + "location (/home/user1/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteResources() {
        // Delete the stream
        AmazonKinesis kinesis = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .build();

        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon Kinesis stream used by the sample. Stream Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        try {
            kinesis.deleteStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The stream doesn't exist.
        }

        // Delete the table
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion("us-west-2")
            .build();
        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library. Table Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        try {
            dynamoDB.deleteTable(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        } catch (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The table doesn't exist.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init();

        if (args.length == 1 && "delete-resources".equals(args[0])) {
            deleteResources();
            return;
        }

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        KinesisAsyncClient kinesisClient = KinesisAsyncClient.builder().region(region).build();
        DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoClient = DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder().region(region).build();
        CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchClient = CloudWatchAsyncClient.builder().region(region).build();

        ConfigsBuilder configsBuilder = new ConfigsBuilder(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME, SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME, 
                kinesisClient, dynamoClient, cloudWatchClient, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory());

        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(
                configsBuilder.checkpointConfig(),
                configsBuilder.coordinatorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.leaseManagementConfig(),
                configsBuilder.lifecycleConfig(),
                configsBuilder.metricsConfig(),
                configsBuilder.processorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.retrievalConfig()
                );


        System.out.printf("Running %s to process stream %s as worker %s...\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                null);

        int exitCode = 0;
        try {
            scheduler.run();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Caught throwable while processing data.");
            t.printStackTrace();
            exitCode = 1;
        }
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2017 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import software.amazon.kinesis.exceptions.InvalidStateException;
import software.amazon.kinesis.exceptions.ShutdownException;
import software.amazon.kinesis.exceptions.ThrottlingException;
import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.InitializationInput;
import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.LeaseLostInput;
import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ProcessRecordsInput;
import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ShardEndedInput;
import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.events.ShutdownRequestedInput;
import software.amazon.kinesis.processor.RecordProcessorCheckpointer;
import software.amazon.kinesis.processor.ShardRecordProcessor;
import software.amazon.kinesis.retrieval.KinesisClientRecord;

/**
 * Processes records and checkpoints progress.
 */
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor implements ShardRecordProcessor {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.class);
    private String kinesisShardId;

    // Backoff and retry settings
    private static final long BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 3000L;
    private static final int NUM_RETRIES = 10;

    // Checkpoint about once a minute
    private static final long CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 60000L;
    private long nextCheckpointTimeInMillis;

    private final CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(InitializationInput initializationInput) {
        LOG.info("Initializing record processor for shard: " + initializationInput.shardId());
        this.kinesisShardId = initializationInput.shardId();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void processRecords(ProcessRecordsInput processRecordsInput) {
        LOG.info("Processing " + processRecordsInput.records().size() + " records from " + kinesisShardId);

        // Process records and perform all exception handling.
        processRecordsWithRetries(processRecordsInput.records());

        // Checkpoint once every checkpoint interval.
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > nextCheckpointTimeInMillis) {
            checkpoint(processRecordsInput.checkpointer());
            nextCheckpointTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process records performing retries as needed. Skip "poison pill" records.
     * 
     * @param list Data records to be processed.
     */
    private void processRecordsWithRetries(List<KinesisClientRecord> list) {
        for (KinesisClientRecord record : list) {
            boolean processedSuccessfully = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
                try {
                    //
                    // Logic to process record goes here.
                    //
                    processSingleRecord(record);

                    processedSuccessfully = true;
                    break;
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    LOG.warn("Caught throwable while processing record " + record, t);
                }

                // backoff if we encounter an exception.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
                }
            }

            if (!processedSuccessfully) {
                LOG.error("Couldn't process record " + record + ". Skipping the record.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process a single record.
     * 
     * @param record The record to be processed.
     */
    private void processSingleRecord(KinesisClientRecord record) {
        // TODO Add your own record processing logic here

        String data = null;
        try {
            // For this app, we interpret the payload as UTF-8 chars.
            data = decoder.decode(record.data()).toString();
            // Assume this record came from AmazonKinesisSample and log its age.
            long recordCreateTime = new Long(data.substring("testData-".length()));
            long ageOfRecordInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - recordCreateTime;

            LOG.info(record.sequenceNumber() + ", " + record.partitionKey() + ", " + data + ", Created "
                    + ageOfRecordInMillis + " milliseconds ago.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOG.info("Record does not match sample record format. Ignoring record with data; " + data);
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            LOG.error("Malformed data: " + data, e);
        }
    }

    /** Checkpoint with retries.
     * @param checkpointer
     */
    private void checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        LOG.info("Checkpointing shard " + kinesisShardId);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
            try {
                checkpointer.checkpoint();
                break;
            } catch (ShutdownException se) {
                // Ignore checkpoint if the processor instance has been shutdown (fail over).
                LOG.info("Caught shutdown exception, skipping checkpoint.", se);
                break;
            } catch (ThrottlingException e) {
                // Backoff and re-attempt checkpoint upon transient failures
                if (i >= (NUM_RETRIES - 1)) {
                    LOG.error("Checkpoint failed after " + (i + 1) + "attempts.", e);
                    break;
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Transient issue when checkpointing - attempt " + (i + 1) + " of "
                            + NUM_RETRIES, e);
                }
            } catch (InvalidStateException e) {
                // This indicates an issue with the DynamoDB table (check for table, provisioned IOPS).
                LOG.error("Cannot save checkpoint to the DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library.", e);
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
            }
        }
    }


    public void shardEnded(ShardEndedInput shardEndedInput) {
        try {
            shardEndedInput.checkpointer().checkpoint();
        } catch (ShutdownException | InvalidStateException e) {
            //
            // Swallow the exception
            //
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void leaseLost(LeaseLostInput leaseLostInput) {

    }


    @Override
    public void shutdownRequested(ShutdownRequestedInput shutdownRequestedInput) {
        try {
            shutdownRequestedInput.checkpointer().checkpoint();
        } catch (ShutdownException | InvalidStateException e) {
            //
            // Swallow the exception
            //
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;

import software.amazon.kinesis.processor.ShardRecordProcessor;
import software.amazon.kinesis.processor.ShardRecordProcessorFactory;

/**
 * Used to create new record processors.
 */
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory implements ShardRecordProcessorFactory {

    @Override
    public ShardRecordProcessor shardRecordProcessor() {
        return new AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor();
    }
}
```